# Mistake on Wikipedia about coordinate change?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading [this Wikipedia article about coordinate change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Change_of_coordinates_of_a_vector).

Say, $\alpha_i$ is some basis of some finite vector space. Then a vector $\xi$ can be written as a coordinate tuple with respect to this basis:

$$ \xi = \sum_i x_i \alpha_i$$

Say $M$ is a matrix that changes the basis, say, $M \alpha_i = \alpha_i'$. Now Wikipedia states:

This means that given a matrix $M$ whose columns are the vectors of the new basis of the space (new basis matrix), the new coordinates for a column vector $v$ are given by the matrix product $M^{−1}v$.

So far so good: If $M \alpha_i = \alpha_i'$ then $ \alpha_i =M^{-1} \alpha_i'$ and therefore

$$ \xi = \sum_i \alpha_i x_i = \sum_i M^{-1}\alpha_i' x_i$$

But now I'm confused: $\xi$ should be a basis independent entity. Only its coordinates should change if the basis changes. But applying $M$ to the equality above we get

$$ M \xi = \sum_i \alpha_i' x_i$$

So when we change the basis the coordinates of $\xi$ (the $x_i$) stay the same but the left hand side changes instead.

> Please could someone help me resolve my confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let there be given two bases $\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\}$ and $\{\alpha'_1, \ldots, \alpha'_n\}$ yielding coordinates $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $(x'_1,\ldots, x'_n)$ respectively for a particular vector $\xi$.

There is indeed a *linear transformation* $M$ (not really a matrix) such that $M\alpha_i=\alpha'_i$ and $\alpha_i=M^{-1}\alpha'_i$ for $i\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$.

The equations 
$$\sum x_i\alpha_i=\xi=\sum x'_i\alpha'_i=\sum x'_iM^{-1}\alpha_i$$

and 
$$\sum x_i M\alpha_i=M\xi=\sum x'_i\alpha_i$$ are both completely valid.

There isn't any contradiction here: $M\xi$ is a completely new vector with coordinates $(x'_1,\ldots, x'_n)$ in the $\alpha$ basis, which is, of course, a completely different thing from $\xi$ which has those same coordinates, but with respect to the $\alpha'$ basis.

I think the thing you're running up against is the difference between [*active* and *passive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation) roles of a linear transformation. By writing $M\xi$ you're probably thinking of an active transformation (it leaves the coordinates alone but moves the basis elements, which will typically move vectors) but you are trying to reconcile that with a coordinate transformation (a passive transformation: the coordinates are changing but the vectors are not) which we think of as moving the coordinates and not the vectors themselves.

When you're dealing with a passive transformation, you typically want to think about a matrix acting on the list of coefficients, and when you want to think about an active transformation you think about a linear transformation acting on abstract vectors.

Comment: I've just started to read your answer. It seems to me that you have swapped the $x$s and $\alpha$s: On the wiki page I linked the $\alpha$s are the vectors and the $x$s are the coordinates. I can still understand your answer but I feel that it would be slightly nicer if you used the same notation as Wikipedia.

Comment: Hm... in the equation you quote I merely substituted the equality $M \alpha_i = \alpha_i'$. It is not so clear to me why this is "going off the rails", Would you elaborate a wee bit more on why this is wrong, please?

Comment: @student Sorry, when you wrote Greek letters on the left of Roman letters, I took that to be the convention where the scalars are Greek. Reading the wiki article though, I see they follow the reverse convention, which I've also seen. This still means that  applying *the matrix $M$* to *the abstract vectors $\alpha_i$ is a problem. It should just be referred to as a linear transformation instead.  I will take time later to revise my answer to fix my notational misunderstanding. Your patience is appreciated.

Comment: @student OK, the answer is revised. I think this is more useful, and you can let me know what can be improved.

Comment: Thank you. I think you could be right about my confusing active and passive transformation. I'm not sure what I was thinking when I was reading that article.

Comment: @student No problem: this is just one of those things everyone gets their head around at some point.